# How to scroll bottom row of TableLayoutPanel into view

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

At runtime I am adding controls to a control that inherits from TableLayoutPanel.  Controls are added one at a time, based on user interaction, not in a loop.

Here's the setup of my control that inherits from the TLP:

```
this.RowCount = 0; 
this.RowStyles.Clear();
this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.VerticalScroll.Enabled = true;
this.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
this.AutoScroll = true
```

And I'm adding user-controls to the bottom of the panel like this:

```
var uc = new FooControl();
this.Controls.Add(uc);
this.SetRow(uc, this.Controls.Count - 1);
this.SetColumn(uc, 0);
```

I would like to scroll that row/control into view.

How is that done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To scroll a control into view in a [`ScrollableControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) like `TableLayoutPanel`, you can use [`ScrollControlIntoView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scrollcontrolintoview(v=vs.110).aspx) method. For example:

```
this.ScrollControlIntoView(uc);
```

*Note:* It doesn't select the control.

Also If you call [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wt11hea(v=vs.110).aspx) method of a control, it will be selected (if selectable) and also its scrollable parent will be scrolled to bring the selected child control into view. For example:

```
uc.Select();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting the VerticalScroll of the Panel but I think it would be better to use ScrollControlIntoView instead.

```
private void panel1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    panel1.ScrollControlIntoView(e.Control);
}
```

or

```
panel.VerticalScroll.Value = panel.VerticalScroll.Maximum
```

Comment: `panel.VerticalScroll.Value = panel.VerticalScroll.Maximum` doesn't actually work.  You might want to test that.